# Can't get li text() from a line

Tags: text, html-lists

```
echo '<script>var newUL = $("<ul>';
for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)
{
    echo "<li>"."abcd"."</li>";
}
echo '</ul>");';
echo "\n";
echo '$("#filemanager li").click(function(){$(this).append(newUL);});</script>';
echo '<script>$("#filemanager li").click(function(){alert($(this).text());}); </script>';
```

"#filemanager" is a div tag

I can't get text from one appended -li- ... it returns text of all appended -li-

Comment: http://editare-prin-ftp.comeze.com/editor.php site where is problem

Answer (score 0):

By `$("#filemanager li")` command you've got a collection.

Try this:

```
$("#filemanager li").each(function(){
    alert($(this).text())})
```